# Поиск по сайту MODx

Tags: modx, ajax, php

Помогите пожалуйста установить поиск по сайту с помощью сниппета `AdvSearch`. Сниппет устанавливается нормально, но когда вводишь в строку слово и нажимаешь на поиск то сразу выдает 500 ошибку, когда ни чего не вписываешь в строку поиска, а просто нажимаешь на кнопку поиск, то выводяться все существующие ресурсы. Сниппет вывожу по [документации](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/AdvSearch)

`[[!AdvSearchForm]] - Форма поиска`

`Results`

`[[!AdvSearch]] - Вывод результата`

Где то было написано что требуется `Zend_Search`, а что это, где это взять и как установить понятия не имею.

Пробовал такие сниппеты как:

**mSearch** (не выводит TV параметры, а точней выводит только первый)

**SimpleSearch** (В постраничной навигации отсутствую кнопки "В начало" "В конец")

Может кто поможет мне в решении данной проблемы, или хотя бы подскажите, может есть какой лучший поиск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто отлично, вы сами даёте ссылку на документацию, но не читали её вообще.

> Requirements
>
> - MODx Revolution 2.0.8 or later
> - PHP5 or later
> - UTF-8 charset
> - php multi-bytes setting ON
> - **Zend Search class from Zend library (See installation chapter)**
> - Jquery 1.5.1 (provided with    AdvSearch)

И, чуть ниже, большими зелеными буквами заголовок: [**Installation of the Zend Search class**](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/AdvSearch#AdvSearch-InstallationoftheZendSearchclass) и 6 элементарных шагов.

Надеюсь, с установкой класса не возникнет проблем.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил. Может есть предложения более лучшего сниппета, может я еще не все опробывал

Comment: Ну вообще тут лидирует simple search: http://modx.com/extras/category/search

Comment: Ну вот я и поставил Simple Search себе, но одно не понравилось, что нету в постраничной навигации кнопок "В начало" "В конец" Или может кто знает как их там реализовать ???

Comment: Сделал все по инструкции все ровно выдает ошибку, ни сниппет а отстой какой то (((